# How to find() two values in array in document (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection filled with documents that each have an object called `alltags`. That object is an array filled with strings. I'm aware I could find a string inside the arrays inside the documents using `collection.find({alltags:"searchstring"})`, but how can I search for an object that contains two strings.

Ex. `collection.find({alltags:"searchstring1", {alltags:"searchstring2"}})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)** operator to query the collection for documents where the value of the **`alltags`** field is an array whose elements include **`searchstring1`** and **`searchstring2`**:

```
db.collection.find( { "alltags": { "$all": [ "searchstring1", "searchstring1" ] } } )
```

It is equivalent to an **[`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)** operation of the specified values; i.e. the following statement:

```
{ "alltags": { "$all": [ "searchstring1" , "searchstring2" ] } }
```

is the same as:

```
{ "$and": [ { "alltags": "searchstring1" }, { "alltags": "searchstring2" } ] }
```